# Phaser - moving projectiles does not work when projectile added to a group

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'm new to Phaser and try to move projectiles. I managed to have the projectile movements working, but to add collision, I created the group this.projectiles. Since this, projectiles are created at the correct spot (near the character, regarding the mouse position) but don't move anymore.

```js
import Bat from "../game/Bat.js";
import Player from "../game/Player.js";
import Projectile from "../game/Projectile.js";
import Phaser from "../lib/phaser.js";

export default class Game extends Phaser.Scene {
  constructor() {
    super("game");
    this.firingRate = 1; // Un tir par seconde
    this.timer = null; // Timer
  }

  preload() {
    this.load.image("tiles", "assets/MasterSimple.png");
    this.load.tilemapTiledJSON("level1", "assets/level1.json");

    //Player
    Player.preload(this);

    //Ennemis
    Bat.preload(this);

    // Projectiles
    Projectile.preload(this);
  }

  create() {
    // Map
    const level1 = this.make.tilemap({
      key: "level1",
      tileWidth: 16,
      tileHeight: 16,
    });
    const tileset = level1.addTilesetImage("MasterSimple", "tiles");

    // Calques
    const eauLayer = level1.createLayer("eau", tileset, 0, 0);
    eauLayer.scale = 3;
    const solLayer = level1.createLayer("sol", tileset, 0, 0);
    solLayer.scale = 3;
    const murLayer = level1.createLayer("mur", tileset, 0, 0);
    murLayer.scale = 3;

    // Personnages
    this.player = new Player(this, 500, 300).setScale(3.5);
    this.cursors = this.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();

    this.physics.add.collider(this.player, eauLayer);
    eauLayer.setCollisionBetween(81, 82);
    eauLayer.setCollisionBetween(64, 66);
    this.physics.add.collider(this.player, murLayer);
    murLayer.setCollisionBetween(110, 140);

    this.player.create();

    // Ennemis
    this.enemies = this.physics.add.group();
    this.bat = new Bat(this, 900, 500).setScale(3);
    this.bat.create();
    this.enemies.add(this.bat);

    // Projectiles
    this.projectiles = this.physics.add.group();

    // Camera
    this.cameras.main.startFollow(this.player);

    this.timer = this.time.addEvent({
      delay: 1000 / this.firingRate,
      callback: () => this.shoot(this.input.activePointer),
      callbackScope: this,
      loop: true, // Répéter
    });
  }

  shoot(pointer) {
    const worldX = this.cameras.main.getWorldPoint(pointer.x, pointer.y).x;
    const worldY = this.cameras.main.getWorldPoint(pointer.x, pointer.y).y;

    const diffX = worldX - this.player.x;
    const diffY = worldY - this.player.y;
    const angleRadian = Math.atan2(diffY, diffX);

    const angleDegre = (angleRadian * 180) / Math.PI;

    // Décalage par rapport au personnage
    const offsetX = 40; // Décalage en X
    const offsetY = 40; // Décalage en Y

    // Calculer les nouvelles coordonnées du projectile
    const position = {
      x: this.player.x + offsetX * Math.cos(angleRadian),
      y: this.player.y + offsetY * Math.sin(angleRadian),
    };

    const target = { x: worldX, y: worldY };

    this.projectile = new Projectile(this, position, target);
    this.projectile.angle = angleDegre;
    this.projectile.create();
    this.projectiles.add(this.projectile); // <== THIS ONE !

  }

  update() {
    this.player.update();

    this.bat.update();

    this.projectiles.getChildren().forEach((projectile) => {
      projectile.update();
    });
  }
}
```

The projectiles are correctly moving if I delete the following line in the shoot() function :

```
this.projectiles.add(this.projectile);
```

However I want it so I can set colliding logics for projectiles and enemies.

Here is the code of my projectile if that can help :

```js
import Phaser from "../lib/phaser.js";

export default class Projectile extends Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Sprite {
  constructor(scene, position, target) {
    super(scene, position.x, position.y, "basic");
    this.target = target;

    scene.add.existing(this);
    scene.physics.add.existing(this);

    const speed = 800;

    this.scene.physics.moveTo(this, target.x, target.y, speed);
  }

  static preload(scene) {
    scene.load.image("basic", "../../assets/Projectiles/rocket.png");
  }

  create() {}

  update() {
    if (
      this.x < 0 ||
      this.x > this.scene.cameras.main.width ||
      this.y < 0 ||
      this.y > this.scene.cameras.main.height
    ) {
      this.destroy();
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that on adding the gameobject to the physics group, the default body values for the group are set on the `this.projectile`. As mentioned in [the documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Group.html).

> *... All Game Objects created by, or added to this Group will automatically be given dynamic Arcade Physics bodies (if they have no body already) and the bodies will receive the Groups default values. ...*

You could use a ["normal" Phaser Group](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.GameObjects.Group.html), a vanilla js array or simply just set the speed after adding the gameobject to the physics group.

**Here a short demo:**
*(In this demo I optimzied some parts of the code, like the `update` function, since looping over all projectiles on update is costly)*

```js
document.body.style = 'margin:0;';

class SampleScene extends Phaser.Scene {
    constructor() {
        super('SampleScene');
    }

    create() {
        let graphics = this.make.graphics();
        graphics.fillStyle(0xffffff);
        graphics.fillRect(0, 0, 4, 4);
        graphics.generateTexture('bullet', 4, 4);

        this.bulletsShot = 0;
        this.player = this.add.rectangle(config.width / 2, config.height / 2, 10, 10, 0xff0000)
            .setDepth(10)
            .setOrigin(.5);

        this.label = this.add.text(10, 10, 'DEMO TEXT')
            .setScale(1.5)
            .setOrigin(0)
            .setStyle({ fontStyle: 'bold', fontFamily: 'Arial' });

        this.bullets = this.physics.add.group({
            collideWorldBounds: true,
        });
        
        this._timer = this.time.addEvent({
            delay: 300,
            callback: () => this.shoot(this.input.activePointer),
            callbackScope: this,
            loop: true,
        });

        this.physics.world.on('worldbounds', (body) => {
            body.gameObject.destroy();
        });

        this.updateLabel();
    }

    updateLabel() {
        this.label.setText(`bullets shoot: ${this.bulletsShot}\nbullets active: ${this.bullets.children.size}`)
    }

    shoot(pointer) {
        let { x, y } = this.player;
        let bullet = new Projectile(this, this.player);
        this.bullets.add(bullet, true);

        bullet.body.onWorldBounds = true;
        let speed = 100;
        let velocity = new Phaser.Math.Vector2(this.input.activePointer.x - this.player.x, this.input.activePointer.y - this.player.y)
            .setLength(speed);

        bullet.body.setVelocity(velocity.x, velocity.y)
        this.bulletsShot++;
        this.updateLabel();
    }
}

class Projectile extends Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Sprite {
    constructor(scene, position) {
        super(scene, position.x, position.y, "bullet");
    }
}

var config = {
    width: 536,
    height: 183,
    physics: {
        default: 'arcade',
    },
    scene: SampleScene,
};

new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser/dist/phaser.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, you were right about setting the speed after adding the projectile to the projectiles group !